# How to scan the nearby mobile operators?

Tags: android, telephony, cellular-network

I am developing an application with utilities in Android. I have developed a wireless network scanner and I would also have to scan the available mobile operators. I managed to get my mobile operator and nearby cells.

Comment: Interesting question, are you trying to determine which cellular networks are in range?

Comment: Yes. 
with TelephonyManager.getNeighboringCellInfo () get the cells that are around, but they are cells of my operator (I think so) and have not found a way to detect other networks in range